# Generating a printable Paper Wallet for Solana like bitaddress.org

Tags: wallet

Is there a similar service like bitaddress.org that can generate printable paper wallets but for Solana addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `solana-keygen` tool. You get it by installing [Solana CLI tools](https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools)

please refer to the [docs](https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide/paper-wallet#creating-a-paper-wallet)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a memory paper wallet to generate a solana address:

**Live Site:**  https://xcubicle.github.io/memorypaperwallet/

**Source:** https://github.com/xcubicle/memorypaperwallet

https://xcubicle.com/memory-paper-wallet-bitcoin-ethereum-monero-ardor-litecoin

Just use any user/pass combination and it will regenerate the address each time. No need to write down any long private key addresses. Just remember it!

FYI, its a project I maintain.